# Creating new columns by adding groups of columns

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'BU': ['Total', 'Total', 'Total', 'CRS', 'CRS', 'CRS'], 
    'Line_Item': ['Revenues','EBT', 'Expenses', 'Revenues', 'EBT', 'Expenses'],
    'Small Business Loans < $100K 2020 ($000)': [100, 120, 0, 200, 190, 210],
    'Small Business Loans < $100K 2019 ($000)': [100, 0, 130, 200, 190, 210],
    'Small Business Loans < $100K 2018 ($000)': [200, 250, 0, 120, 0, 190],
    'Small Business Loans $100K-$250K 2020 ($000)': [100, 120, 0, 200, 190, 210],
    'Small Business Loans $100K-$250K 2019 ($000)': [100, 0, 130, 200, 190, 210],
    'Small Business Loans $100K-$250K 2018 ($000)': [200, 250, 0, 120, 0, 190]
    'Multi Family Loans 2020 ($000)': [100, 120, 0, 200, 190, 210],
    'Multi Family Loans 2019 ($000)': [100, 0, 130, 200, 190, 210],
    'Multi Family Loans 2018 ($000)': [200, 250, 0, 120, 0, 190]
})
```

I wish to create new columns which add 'Small Business Loans < $100K 2020 ($000)' to 'Small Business Loans $100K-$250K 2020 ($000)' and 'Small Business Loans < $100K 2019 ($000)' to 'Small Business Loans $100K-$250K 2019 ($000)'.

Basically I want to the see the sum of loans by year

The actual data set has many rows and other such sets of columns.

If the columns were identically named in two dataframes I could have used

```
df_add = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** For the Small Business Loans, try a `regex` filter:

```py
s = '\$(000)'
years = range(2018, 2021)

df.assign(**{
    f'SBL {y} {s}': df.filter(regex=fr'Small Business Loans.*{y}.*{s}').sum(1)
    for y in years
})
```

To combine both MF and SBL, change `Small Business Loans` to `(Multi Family|Small Business Loans)`:

```py
df.assign(**{
    f'Loans {y} {s}': df.filter(regex=fr'(Multi Family|Small Business Loans).*{y}.*{s}').sum(1)
    for y in years
})
```

---

You can [**`assign()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) the new columns with a comprehension:

```py
df = df.assign(**{
    f'{i}Q16': df[f'{i}Q16-1'] + df[f'{i}Q16-2'] for i in [1,2,3]
})
```

Can also do the summing with a `like` filter:

```py
df = df.assign(**{
    f'{i}Q16': df.filter(like=f'{i}Q16').sum(1) for i in [1,2,3]
})
```

Output:

```
      BU Line_Item  1Q16-1  2Q16-1  3Q16-1  1Q16-2  2Q16-2  3Q16-2  1Q16  2Q16  3Q16
0  Total  Revenues     100     100     200     100     100     200   200   200   400 
1  Total       EBT     120       0     250     120       0     250   240     0   500 
2  Total  Expenses       0     130       0       0     130       0     0   260     0 
3    CRS  Revenues     200     200     120     200     200     120   400   400   240 
4    CRS       EBT     190     190       0     190     190       0   380   380     0 
5    CRS  Expenses     210     210     190     210     210     190   420   420   380
```

Comment: I had same approach in mind. +1 for filter.

Comment: hi: the cols in the actual data set are pretty complex. for example, i have a set of 'Small Business Loans < $100K 2020 ($000)' and 'Small Business Loans $100K-$250K 2020 ($000)' and 'Small Business Loans $250K-$1M 2020 ($000)'. All ranging from 2010 to 2020. Not sure how to apply the filter?

Comment: @postcolonialist so you want one column for `SBL_Under100K_2020 + SBL_100K_2020 + SBL_250K_2020`, another column for `SBL_Under100K_2021 + SBL_100K_2021 + SBL_250K_2021`, etc?

Comment: Yes. I want to add the loans for each year. Thanks

Comment: @postcolonialist kindly update your question with the more complex form

Comment: @postcolonialist maybe something like a regex filter: `df.assign(**{f'SBL{y}': df.filter(regex=f'Small Business Loans.*{y}').sum(1) for y in range(2010,2021)})`

Comment: Regex that picks up the trailing characters 2020 ($000) etc. perhaps?

Comment: @postcolonialist updated with a suffixed version

Comment: Hmm...giving me zeros for the sum of the "Small Business"

Comment: @postcolonialist fixed (i think)

Comment: This works. Thanks tons. Any thoughts on the "Multi Family" version? Else I can do it manually. I was trying something with iloc

Comment: @postcolonialist should work with a direct replacement (`SBL` -> `MF` and `Small Business Loans` -> `Multi Family`)

Comment: Yes. But if I wish to add SB Loans to Multi Family loans?

Comment: @postcolonialist updated the answer if you mean this: `MF_2020+SBL_U100K_2020+SBL_100K_2020+SBL_250K_2020`, then `MF_2021+SBL_U100K_2021+SBL_100K_2021+SBL_250K_2021`, ...

Comment: you are god! no kidding.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to do

```py
df['1Q16-sum'] = df['1Q16-1'] + df['1Q16-2']
df['2Q16-sum'] = df['2Q16-1'] + df['2Q16-2']
df['3Q16-sum'] = df['3Q16-1'] + df['3Q16-2']
```

or with a loop

```py
# python 3.6+
for i in range(1,4):
    df[f'{i}Q16-sum'] = df[f'{i}Q16-1'] + df[f'{i}Q16-2']

# or other python versions
for i in range(1,4):
    id = str(i) + "Q16"
    df[id+'-sum'] = df[id+'-1'] + df[id+'-2']
```

giving you

```
      BU Line_Item  1Q16-1  2Q16-1  3Q16-1  1Q16-2  2Q16-2  3Q16-2  1Qq6-sum  2Qq6-sum  3Qq6-sum
0  Total  Revenues     100     100     200     100     100     200       200       200       400
1  Total       EBT     120       0     250     120       0     250       240         0       500
2  Total  Expenses       0     130       0       0     130       0         0       260         0
3    CRS  Revenues     200     200     120     200     200     120       400       400       240
4    CRS       EBT     190     190       0     190     190       0       380       380         0
5    CRS  Expenses     210     210     190     210     210     190       420       420       380
```

is that it ?

Comment: Well I have many sets of columns. This would be very cumbersome. Thanks

Comment: @postcolonialist I added another way using a loop, if you have the same pattern of column names